# PDO Driver not found when execute command

Tags: database, symfony, orm

I am facing a problem with my database. Context: Web application referencing members, where it is possible to import members via an xls file repository, a processing is done to save it in database. I try to execute a command that is supposed to run in the background on the production environment, but on the development environment it must be executed manually, to perform the import of the files that have as states "to import". Problem during the execution, the command displays that there are driver problems with PDO, it can't find them.
Any idea where the problem could come from?
You will find here with the detailed errors, as well as the config.yml of the symfony 5 project

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 128:
                                                          
  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver  
                                                          

In Exception.php line 18:
                         
  could not find driver  
                         

In PDOConnection.php line 40:
                         
  could not find driver
```

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        types:
            phone_number: Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\PhoneNumberType
        server_version: "%doctrine_server_version%"
        options:
            1002: 'SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", ""))'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
                regexp: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Regexp
                replace: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Replace
                DATE_FORMAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
        mappings:
            gedmo_tree:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTree # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
```

Comment: Can you show us your .env file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused I found where my mistake came from. The configuration files were set up correctly but I hadn't run bash before running the command, so it didn't recognize the locally binded augments. Really sorry for this question ... very stupid

Comment: Please edit your question if you need to add more context to it

Answer (score 0):

Check if your DATABASE_URL host is correct on your .env file.
You should have something like `DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbuser:dbpassword@127.0.0.1:3306/something`

If it's correctly setup, check your local installation (usually with `sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql`)

Also check your php.ini file if `extension=pdo_mysql` is not commented.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here comes from you env file. Make sure you wrote the correct database information there:
`DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"`

Also, make sure that you did create your database correctly and you can find here in your database.